# Scope of locks when using TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, serialization, locking, transaction-isolation

The following link describes the serializable transaction isolation level.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlcat/archive/2011/02/20/concurrency-series-basics-of-transaction-isolation-levels.aspx

Suppose I have one user updating table `[dbo].[Table_A]`.  And another user is updating table `[dbo].[Table_B]`.  And I want to serialize these two update statements (meaning wait for the first to finish before the second one begins), despite the fact that we are touching different tables.  I'm guessing I cannot use a table lock, but perhaps a range lock would accomplish this.  Can someone help me understand what the code may look like?  Or won't this work with transaction isolation level functionality in SQL Server 2008?

Comment: Why would you want to serialize updates to different tables? What problem are you trying to solve with that?

Comment: I am dealing with a directed acyclic graph (poly-hierarchy) data model.  One table is joined with the other and enforces inheritance.

Comment: So you are updating `table_b` using data from `table_a`? Could you please post your update statements?

Comment: For the sake of argument, let's suppose they are not joined.  Because I have examples where I have no joins.  update [dbo].[Table_A] set x=1 & update [dbo].[Table_B] set y=1

Comment: I don't see why you can't do this in parallel

Comment: Suppose you have a hierarchy and multiple users are dragging and dropping nodes where they please at the same time.  In that case, we have parent/child records changing constantly, and both foreign keys are referenced from the same table.  In my case, I have a poly-hierarchy, so I want all application operations serialized for the beta release, to avoid complications.

Comment: MacGyver: this is better explained with examples.

Comment: I'll be back with examples when the applications is functioning.  For now, I want to simplify development so we don't waste time.  What you gave me is great in the mean time!

Comment: seems you've chosen the right nick! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may place application locks:

```
EXEC  sp_getapplock @resource = 'my_resource_token', @lockMode = 'Exclusive'

UPDATE ...

EXEC  sp_releaseapplock @resource = 'my_resource_token'
```

This will lock if another session has aquired `my_resource_token`.

Comment: I will be posting details later to make the application perform better.  Right now, this is perfect.  Thanks!  So just so I'm understanding, any command run on the database is serialized?

Comment: @MacGyver: yes, everything between `getapplock` and `releaseapplock` can only be executed by one transaction at a time.

Comment: What is the best way to find locks using this methodology?  Using 'sp_lock'?

Comment: @MacGyver: `sys.dm_tran_locks`